# ValueError: `X_pca` does not have enough PCs. Rerun `sc.pp.pca` with adjusted `n_comps`

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, pca, scanpy

I get an error with my code like this:

```
for adata in [adata_fish]:
    sc.pp.neighbors(adata, n_neighbors=10, n_pcs=50)
    sc.tl.leiden(adata)
```

and because of this code I can't run this code:

```
# Plot Leiden clusters on tSNE 
for adata in [adata_fish]:
    print(adata.uns["name"], ":")
    sc.pl.tsne(adata, color=["leiden"], cmap="tab20")
    sc.pl.tsne(adata, color=markers, layer="sqrt_norm")
```

which gives me an error message "KeyError: 'Could not find key leiden in .var_names or .obs.columns.'"

Not sure where it went wrong...

Comment: What is the error for the first block of code?